# MySQL Dependencies in Maven doesn't work (Eclipse IDE)

Tags: spring-boot, eclipse, server, dependencies, mysql-connector

I have some issues with my Maven dependencies. It doesn't seem to be able to connect to my MySQL server:

> D:\react\reactProject\02-backend\Spring-Boot-App-Library\target>java -jar Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
>
> Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.0)
>
> 2023-06-22T03:18:39.853+02:00 ERROR 20036 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFact
> ory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibarnate.dialect.MyS
> QL8Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
> 2023-06-22T03:18:39.855+02:00  WARN 20036 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initi
> alization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory'
> defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service
> [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.d
> ialect.Dialect]
> 2023-06-22T03:18:39.856+02:00  INFO 20036 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
> 2023-06-22T03:18:39.891+02:00  INFO 20036 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
> 2023-06-22T03:18:39.897+02:00  INFO 20036 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
> 2023-06-22T03:18:39.959+02:00  INFO 20036 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
>
> Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
> 2023-06-22T03:18:40.036+02:00 ERROR 20036 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/spr
> ingframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcE
> nvironment] due to: Unable to resolve name [org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[s
> pring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spr
> ing-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:
> 6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-
> 6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:
> 6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spri
> ng-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar!/:6
> .0.9]
> at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spr
> ing-boot-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar!/:3.1.0]
> at com.luv2code.SpringBootAppLibrary.SpringBootAppLibraryApplication.main(SpringBootAppLibraryApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> ]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
> ]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment] due to:
> Unable to resolve name [org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect] as strategy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:277) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Fina
> l.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:239) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.
> Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.j
> ar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.relational.Database.(Database.java:45) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.getDatabase(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:229) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final
> .jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:197) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!
> /:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:166) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/
> :6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1380) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2
> .Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1451) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Fi
> nal.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistence
> Provider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean
> .java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[
> spring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.
> 0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[s
> pring-orm-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:181
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1766)
> ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar!/:6.0.9]
> 24 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.spi.StrategySelectionException: Unable to resolve name [org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect] as strat
> egy [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:154) ~[hibernate-co
> re-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:236) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.F
> inal.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:189) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.F
> inal.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.constructDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.j
> ar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:86) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:
> 6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:274) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.
> Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.F
> inal.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:119) ~[hibernate-core-6.
> 2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:264) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.Fina
> l.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 39 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:123) ~[hibernate-core-6.
> 2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.selectStrategyImplementor(StrategySelectorImpl.java:150) ~[hibernate-co
> re-6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 47 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.F
> inal.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467) ~[na:na]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-core-6.
> 2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 48 common frames omitted
> Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: null
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-6.2.2.F
> inal.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 53 common frames omitted
> Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
> at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-
> SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:205) ~[hibernate-core
> -6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 53 common frames omitted
> Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
> at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587) ~[na:na]
> at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:149) ~[Spring-Boot-App-Library-0.0.1-
> SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:205) ~[hibernate-core
> -6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 53 common frames omitted
> Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibarnate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520) ~[na:na]
> at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:205) ~[hibernate-core
> -6.2.2.Final.jar!/:6.2.2.Final]
> 53 common frames omitted
>
> D:\react\reactProject\02-backend\Spring-Boot-App-Library\target>

My application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
```

I have no idea where the error might be hiding, my Mysql8Dialect class is written correctly. Does anyone know more?

Answer (score 0):

In the error log you provided it says org.**hibarnate**.dialect.MySQL8Dialect

That appears to be a typo and has to be `org.hibernate`. Search your entire project for that misspelled package, it might be in a different .properties file that overwrites the one you provided in your question.

Comment: I found the class, but it is crossed out. Can it be deprecated?

Comment: Even if it was deprecated, there wouldnt be a ClassNotFoundException. Have you searched for 'hibarnate' in your project? Are there search results?

Comment: Yes, I found the MySQL8Dialect.class in the org.hibernate package. The only thing I could find out was that the class is deprecated

Comment: Yes I'm aware that you found **the class**. But you have to search for **the misspelled package**, search project-wide for `hibarnate`. The correct name is hib**e**rnate